# What is the name of Brokkr's forge in Norse mythology?

Tags: norse, mythohistory

I've read up and searched on Google. I've also read stories on the matter but I noticed that every item around Brokkr's and Eitri's workshop seems named except the magical forge with which they built the items for the gods.

Does anyone know the name of the forge itself? Does it have a name?

Comment: If it does, you definitely came to the right place to find the answer.  Welcome to Mythology!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Unknown**

First, note that it's Brokk's brother who is clearly the master smith and does the actual smithing, while Brokk works the bellows. This brother is given as either Eitri or Sindri in different manuscripts of *Snorri's Edda*. The name Sindri also appears in *[Völuspa](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/poe/poe03.htm)*, where it is told he had a hall in Nithavellir ("the Dark fields").

The forge in itself goes unnamed in the story (it's short, you can read it in a few minutes. See e.g. [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Prose_Edda/Sk%C3%A1ldskaparm%C3%A1l#Loke.27s_Wager_With_the_Dwarves)). Furthermore, I can't recall any forge that are given a name in Norse mythology. It would seem that forges were not in themselves considered that important, and certainly not when compared to the skill of the smith, which is emphasized several times in several completely different tales.

Answer (score 3):

Also, Norse myth has these gaps. Thor's goats have names, while Freyja's cats don't (that we know of). The forge may or may not have had a name in the myths, but @andejons is right to say that it was the smiths that were the focus of the story.